# Python and Google App Engine: How to import a custom module?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, module

I have got a custom module called `subprocess32.py`, I have placed this in:

```
/Python/2.7/site-packages/subprocess32
```

along with `__init.py__`

I have tried importing this package / module in a python shell using

```
from subprocess32 import subprocess32
```

this works fine I  can use the functions etc.

I want to use this module within my goolgle app engine application, I have tried

```
from subprocess 32 import subprocess32
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named subprocess32
```

I have also tried putting the `subprocess32` folder and its contents within the apps folder, and point the `sys.path` at it before input but no joy.

Any help would be appreciated many thanks.

Comment: As Daniel Roseman has said below there is no point trying to import it. This moudle is a backport of the python 3.2 subprocess module and you can't run it on appengine. I suggest you look at the docs on the Python runtime sandbox and understand what it's limitations are before you go to much further, it will save you a lot of time down the track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point installing it in your site-packages directory. That only exists on your local machine, obviously: it won't be included when you deploy and you'd therefore get errors when you tried to import it in production. To prevent you from doing just that, the development server runs inside a sandbox that does not import from that directory either - and it also prevents you from tweaking sys.path.

Instead, just put it inside your project directory and import it from there.

**Edit** Actually, now I come to think of it, I don't think this will help you. You don't say what your `subprocess32` module does, but if it's in any way related to the standard subprocess module, you simply won't be able to use it on GAE. There is no system for you to shell out to, and no way to execute arbitrary commands. You probably need to explain exactly what you're trying to do with that module.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I should probably have looked into that before I started developing my system. I am going to change how I serve my website. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `subprocess32` is valid python module.  You should copy and paste this `subprocess32` module to your project root directory.
And then try to import it.

Comment: Thanks, it is importing properly now, it just doesn't work because of the module subprocess :( ah well.